# Activating/Deactivating aif ports using a script

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, ax

I've searched google and also this site but am having trouble finding any examples for this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for AifPortManager::deployPort('PORT_NAME'); and AifPortManager::undeployPort('PORT_NAME'); ?